# Go to Other URL And Anchor When Onclicking An Image In A JS Slideshow

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to web programming. I've just coded (with reference) a JS Slideshow successfully, but now I want to add an onclick function to each image of the slideshow,  **so that when an image is clicked, it directs to a new URL or anchor.**

Here is the intention. When clicking an image within the slideshow:

1. go to a new URL (new browser window)
2. go to an anchor # of the same page (same browser window)
3. go to an anchor # of another page (same browser window)

Googling results I see there are too many JS methods. And I don't really know where and what to add into my code (I tried, but of course not working). The methods like  *document.getElementById(imageID).onclick*  or  *.href*  and make things complicated.

I just want to see if there is a very simple method, no need fancy, a few code only would be good. My code below: Only **head** and **body** are used for the slideshow as shown:

//============This is my HTML header (CSS):

```
<head>
   <style id="compiled-css" type="text/css">
        #image1 {
            opacity:1;
            transition: opacity 0.1s; 
        }
        #image1.fadeOut {
            opacity:0;
        }
   </style>  
</head>
```

//============This is the HTML body with JS slideshow codes:

```
    <div>
        <img id="image1" />
    </div>

    <script>
        var imgArray = [
            'http://my.image/imgs/slide1.jpg',
            'http://my.image/imgs/slide2.jpg',
            'http://my.image/imgs/slide3.jpg'],
            curIndex = 0;
            imgDuration = 3000;

        function slideShow() {
            document.getElementById('image1').className += "fadeOut";
            setTimeout(function() {
                document.getElementById('image1').src = imgArray[curIndex];
                document.getElementById('image1').width = 530;
                document.getElementById('image1').height = 400;
                document.getElementById('image1').className = "";        
            },100);   
            curIndex++;
            if (curIndex == imgArray.length) { curIndex = 0; }
            setTimeout("slideShow()", imgDuration);
        }
        slideShow();
    </script>
</body>
```

I don't really know where the "go to URL" should be. I guess it must be in a `<script>`? I just wish to have the simplest method to do that "each image onclick to URL" functionality, within the slideshow. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing would probably be to wrap each `img` tag in an `a` tag which links to the correct URL. No need to use JS for that part.

```
<div>
    <a href = "image1url">
        <img id="image1"/>
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A partial solution to your problem is to add an onclick attribute to your img tag as follows:

```
<img onclick="changeUrl()" id="image1" />
```

Then add the changeUrl function to be run under where your invoke slideShow function (or anywhere really)

```
.....//continued code
slideShow();
function changeUrl() {
    window.open("https://www.google.com"); // Enter any url here.
}
```

Not sure what else you wanted to accomplish, but I hope this helps! Keep learning!